# Basic math question about understanding variables.

Tags: analysis

I'm working through `brilliant.org's` 'using variables' section in their `basic math` course. I'm trying to understand the following and not sure what I am doing wrong, or maybe I'm understanding it correctly?

[Here's the statement](https://brilliant.org/practice/using-variables/?p=8) `5 (1-x) + 6x = 5-5x + 6x = 5 + x`

If x=5, then in my calculations I do the following:

For the first part before the = sign:
1-5=-4 and 6x = 30, therefore 5x-4 = -20 + 30 = 10

For the 2nd part
5x = 25 so 5-25 + -20 + 30 = 10

For the 3rd part
5+5 = 10

Now I actually write it out, I see they all equal 10, is this actually correct?

Comment: Yes: it uses properties of multiplication and addition to show $5(1-x)+6x=5+x$

Comment: @Henry Maybe I just got confused cause it was dealing with minus values. Thank you. I will beat math dyslexia ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is a simple equation and you can solve it by isolating the x, so yes, this is correct!

Comment: Simple, unless one is dyslexic, in which case the numbers have wings. It truly makes things very difficult. Just imagine if your equation moves around like a kaleidoscope of little butterflies! ;)

Comment: well i hope you will get more familiar with this, can you pleas mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Well, thank you. I'm trying to ascertain whether or not it is 'correct' :) Or whether it added anything. I mean, it's certainly not wrong. I think what is challenging is that the first part will always end up with a negative number, (that threw me off). That is, after one has told the numbers to 'SIT!' like a dog, and stay where they were put.

Comment: i do not understand what do you mean by "the first part will always end up with a negative number"

Comment: Well that's probably exactly what I don't understand. Hang on...

Comment: Ok, I'm talking about `5 (1-x)`. Unless x is a negative number, one or zero the answer to this part will be a negative number. I think.

Comment: when you try to calculate    5 (1-x) + 6x    you obtain 
5*(-4) + 6x   so
-20 + 6 * 5   so
-20 + 30   so in the end it will result positive